# QT: Position tabs within QTabBar block

Tags: qt, tabs, positioning, qtabbar

There is a QTabBar element with a vertical size policy which is expanding. I want to make the tabs to be aligned to the bottom of the QTabBar element box, but they are always appearing from the top.

I have tried styling QTabBar and QTabBar::tab with different combinations of `vertical-align: bottom`, `alignment: bottom;`, `bottom:0;` but with zero luck. It seems that the only alignment that actually work is when I align horizontally.

**Current results:**

[image]

The tabs are separated from where the content will go. And before suggesting me to not use an expanding vertical policy. I **have** to do it like this, I have my reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget alignment can be set in the containing layout, and you have to use a non-zero stretch value:

```
vbox->addWidget(tabBar, 1, Qt::AlignBottom);
vbox->addWidget(otherWidget, 1);
```

The tab will be correctly aligned, with empty space above it, but that space won't be a part of the QTabBar (the expanding policy will be ignored).

If you need to put something in the space above the `QTabBar`, you could insert it at the bottom of another intermediary `QWidget` and insert that widget into the layout instead of the  `QTabBar`.